# How to post values to a url,at the same time the url is opened in a modal window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this

**HTML**

```
 <a class="iframe button pink" href="http://www.google.com" > 
 Pay Now <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.fethr.com/clients/res/buttonmodal.css">
 <script src="http://www.fethr.com/clients/res/buttonmodal.js"></script></a>
```

This is a button on which if I click,the link opens in a modal window.

I have a form in which I add some values to it,when I click submit on the form it should post the values to  "www.google.com",which is a web service (though its not :P,here for demo purpose"),at the same time open the link in the modal window. Is this possible?

All Im trying to do is,when I click submit on the form,the values should be posted to the url as well as opened in a modal window.

Comment: Create the iframe, then post to the iframe.

Comment: @KevinB Can you be bit more precise?Explain it?

Comment: There isn't much to explain, though i have no idea how you would implement it into the modal library you're using. `$("<iframe>").attr("name","theiframe").hide().appendTo("body"); $("#myform").attr("target",theiframe).submit();` In that snippet, you would append it to your modal rather than the body, and you wouldn't hide it.